# Entity Framework DBContext Scaffold - Oracle Data Model Naming Convention Issue

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, scaffolding

I'm working on a `web-api` project created in `.NET6` and I'm using `Entity Framework Core (6.0)` in it. I have already designed `Oracle database` So I've to use `database-first` approach for my `project`. For this purpose, when I try to generate the `data-models` using `EF DBContext Scaffolding` with the below command, It successfully generates all the relevant `data-models`.

> **dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=SKL)));User Id=BOR;Password=myPassword;" Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore -o Models\BOR -c "EF_BORContext" -f --no-onconfiguring**

But the issue is that; its generating the `data-models` having name with first character in `upper-case` and all other characters are in `lower-case`. But I want to follow `PascalCase` for my `data-model` names.

For example, the generated `data-model` for one of my `entity` named as `APPGROUP`;
[image]

I want to follow `PascalCase` convention for my `ClassName` and `ClassPropertiese`. Is there any way to fix it? I try to find solution on `Google` and `StackOverflow` but couldn't get any fix.

Comment: Post code as *text* not images. Images can't be copied, compiled, tested or googled

Comment: FYI Entity Framework and Entity Framework *Core* are totally different things, your tags are kind of confusing, you tagged with .NET (Core) 6 but also Entity Framework 6 which doesn't work out, EF 6 is for .NET *Framework*

Comment: Furthermore, by using the `database first` approach your telling EF Core to use the names from your database. To fix this you can either rename your tables (and columns) in your database, rename name them in your code and use the EF Core annotations (check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations#table-and-column)) to map them correctly to existing tables, use the [fluent API to do the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42191152/9363973) or rename your tables and columns and switch to the `code first` approach

Comment: Code from the images doesn't need to be tested. Its just a snapshot which I want to share to have a clear image of problem. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: You achieved the exact opposite. Post the text instead. You don't need to post the entire class, only the class name and a couple of properties. It's *us* that want to copy and test this code.

Comment: Thank You @PanagiotisKanavos. I'll keep it in my note for the next time. :-)

Comment: Besides, you didn't post the table names. It's unclear whether you want to preserve the original casing or introduce Pascal casing no matter what. I think there are SO answers that show how to use a custom naming convention that uses Humanizer to pascal-case phrases.

Comment: Hi @MindSwipe
Actually It works fine if I use `SQL Server Database` and it follows `PascalCase`. But when I try to generate `data-models` for my `Oracle database`, the naming convention got disturbed. I have hundreds of `tables` and its impossible for me to add `data-annotation` for every table/column for every time.

Comment: Have you tried using the `--use-database-names` parameter ?

Comment: Well, are your tables/ columns named in a PascalCase manner? Because if not, how is EF supposed to figure out what a word is, and what isn't, i.e which letter to capitalise? As Panagiotis Kanavos pointed out, there may be some way to customise the naming EF generates

Comment: Yes, I tried `--use-database-names` and it generates all caps. It must follow `C#` rule to follow `PascalCase` for `Class name and Properties`.

Comment: You mean the table names are all-caps? Are you asking how to get EF Core to recognize words in unseparated strings and properly case them? Please post the relevant information in the question itself. As Text!. Actual table names, expected names, what you got instead.

Comment: `SQL Server` follows `PascalCase` in default, that's why it works fine for `SQL Server`. But for `Oracle`, every `table/column` name is in `capital by default`. So it comes with the naming convention issue in `Oracle` and that's why I can't use `--use-database-names`. I hope you understand now! @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: No, SQL Server has no default naming conventions. It *does* preserve the casing you used when creating the table, but that's not significant. You still haven't posted the necessary information. It's not about whether others understand you, you need to provide enough information so others don't have to guess. I've worked with both Oracle and SQL Server for years, I know about their quirks, but I still can't understand what you expect. If Oracle returns `THISISATABLENAME` why do you expect any library to convert that to `ThisIsATableName` ? Or should it be `ThisIsaTableName`? That's not trivial

Comment: If that's what you ask, this requires natural language processing. Even if you used a library like [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer) you wouldn't be able to convert `THISISATABLENAME`. It's another matter if the object has distinct eg `THIS_IS_A_TABLE_NAME` or `"THIS IS A TABLE NAME"`