EntityFrameworkCore - Can we create an Entity From a creation request class?
Let's say I have this class
public class Person {
    public required Guid Id { get; set;}
    public required string Name { get; set; }
    // ...
}

I like the required keyword so at a compiler level I always know that I have a value there.
But when I want to create a new Person, I want that the database generate me an Id and not the code.
Idealy, I would want to be able to give to EntityFramework a "CreatePersonRequest" class like this:
public class CreatePersonRequest {
    public required string Name { get; set;}
    // ...
}

Is there a way to generate a Person from a CreatePersonRequest in EntityFramework?
Like if I can link the two classes in my DbContext or something like that?
I know I can do it without the required attribute, but our sonarqube mark it as a code smell and I dont have the control on its rules (and he's also right because it is a field that could be null without required)
Thanks in advance!

What's the point of such a class? EF is an ORM, it's job is to give the impression of working with an object database or in-memory entities, not database tables. It loads entire graphs of objects in memory and when you ask it to persist changes, it saves changes in all tracked objects at once.

the database generate me an Id that requires properly configuring the database table, not the entities. You can tell your ORM (in this case EF) that the key is database-generated, and if you create tables from the model, the ORM can create CREATE TABLE statements with the correct columns and settings

Maybe AutoMapper library to copy the properties across?

There's no mapping involved here. The OP is mixing up concepts and probably is trying to apply CQRS to DbContext. That doesn't mean having a request class in the DbContext at all. Different DbContexts can be used to modify the data and query the data for reporting purposes, eg showing them in a grid. The reporting contexts can have tracking automatically disabled, or become read-only by overriding and disabling SaveChanges. A DbContext isn't a database model or connection, it's a Unit-of-Work.

A Request class would make sense in eg MediatR, with handlers for specific application requests. A handler that creates a new customer registration could use a single DbContext to load lookup data and create a new customer

As mentonned by the comments, I was indeed trying to apply CQRS to the DBContext.
I forgot that you can make more than one DbContext and maybe it could be a solution, but in my case I don't think it would work.
The point of not having an id in the creation request was important (to enforce that no one can add their id) but the Entity need an Id when we are inserting.
If it was an another field then an Id it should work, but in this case, no.
It's not a clean solution, but if someone want to make something like this but not for an entity without an Id in the createRequest, you can make another DbContext (ex: CreateDbContext) and have DBSet(s) of yours CreationRequests and add the table name to the Entity (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42191152/11819193).
Interesting reading about this (CQRS and Efcore): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2016/november/data-points-cqrs-and-ef-data-models
For my case, I will separate my classes and make a Person and PersonEntity classes (Business and Infra) and hope for the best.
So for my case, no it's not possible
Thanks everybody!
